# Is there a better way to chain strings together than multiple push_str() calls?

Tags: rust

I would like to chain strings together. This is my code:

```
let mut string_to_send = String::new();
string_to_send.push_str("<hi,");
string_to_send.push_str(&some_int.to_string());
string_to_send.push_str(",");
string_to_send.push_str(&another_int.to_string());
string_to_send.push_str(">");
```

Something tells me there is a nicer way to do it, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `format!`:

```
let mut string_to_send = format!("<hi,{},{}>", some_int, another_int);
```

As [Holloway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916917/holloway) points out in the comments, since [Rust 1.58](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/01/13/Rust-1.58.0.html) you can capture identifiers in format strings:

```
let mut string_to_send = format!("<hi,{some_int},{another_int}>");
```

Comment: And if you're using a recent version of rust,  you can use the interpolation version `format!("<hi,{some_int},{another_int}>")`

Comment: The `string_to_send` variable doesn't need to be mutable in Your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) for this

```rust
let string_to_send = [
    "<hi",
    &10.to_string(),
    ",",
    &11.to_string(),
    ">"
].concat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation with the `+` operator:

```
let string_to_send =
    "<hi,".to_string() + &some_int.to_string() + "," + &another_int.to_string() + ">";
```

The converted `&String` values of the int's become coerced into `&str` arguments before the call of the `+` operator.